# Calcular subtotal mesmo que não sejam preenchidos todos os campos

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um formulário onde precisam ser digitados valores de procedimentos para serem calculados no final, porém nem sempre serão digitados os valores em todos os campos. Queria saber como é a validação para o total do procedimento sair mesmo se for digitado valores somente em dois campos por exemplo. Além disso, no cálculo não tá saindo o que tem após a vírgula. Por exemplo: se eu coloco 12,50 + 12,50 só sai 24 e não 25,00

Comment: Podes colocar aqui um exemplo do HTML que tens e o código que estás a usar para calcular?

Comment: Muito ampla a sua pergunta visto que entre os campos podem haver operações matemáticas de soma, subtração, multiplicação, divisão, percentual. Melhor fazer o que o Sergio pediu.

Comment: Quando algum campo não é preenchido acontece algum problema?

Comment: Bem-vinda Anne, esse post lhe será muito útil para as suas próximas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Esse também https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/

Comment: Não deixe de marcar uma resposta como aceita caso tenha resolvido sua dificuldade. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

De uma maneira geral fiz uma rotina que pode ser facilmente adaptada a qualquer tipo de operação e quantidade de campos.

Basta adicionar os campos, recuperar os valores e fazer os devidos cálculos na variável `total`

```js
  //formata o resultado para reais e decimais com virgula
  function reais(n) {
    var l = Math.floor(n);
    var r = Math.round((100*n)%100);
    if (r<10) return "R$"+l+",0"+r;
    if (r==100) return "R$"+(l+1)+",00";
    return "R$"+l+"."+r;
  }

  function calculate(f) {
    //retorno dos valores dos campos
    var id1=document.getElementById('id1').value;
    var id2=document.getElementById('id2').value;
    var id3=Number(document.getElementById('id3').value);
    var id4=document.getElementById('id4').value;
    var id5=document.getElementById('id5').value;
    //para não invalidar o resultado caso haja alguma divisão no total
    if(id5==""){
       id5=1;
    }
    //aqui as operações envolvendo os campos
    var total=(((id1*id2)+id3)-id4)/id5;
    f.total.value=reais(total);

  }
```

```html
<form>
  Quantidade 
  <input type="text" name="input1"t id="id1">
  Preço Unitário
  <input type="text" name="input2" id="id2"><br>
  Imposto
  <input type="text" name="input3" id="id3"><br>
  Desconto
  <input type="text" name="input4" id="id4"><br>
  Parcelas
  <input type="text" name="input5" id="id5">

  <p>
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      Resultado:</td><td><input type=text name=total size=8>
    </td></tr>
  </table>
  <p>
  <input type=button value=Calculate onClick="calculate(this.form);"> 
</form>
```

> O operador `+` pode te surpreender, dependendo da forma que você o usa.

- Todo mundo sabe que o operador `+` serve para ao menos duas coisas: somar números e concatenar strings!
- No exemplo da resposta a variável `var id3` foi transformada em numero com a função `Number` para efetuar a operação de adição pois caso contrário haveria uma concatenação.

> Ao invés de usar a função `Number` na variável `var id3` poderíamos usar o próprio operador `+` para converter-lo em numero.

**Veja como:**

No lugar de:

```
var id3=Number(document.getElementById('id3').value);
```

Use

```
var id3=document.getElementById('id3').value;
```

E substitua a `var total` por

```
var total=(((id1*id2)+(+id3))-id4)/id5;
```

**Exemplo**

```js
//operador + para conveeter em numero
console.log(10 + +'10');
//sem o operador +
console.log(10 + '10');
```